# Keynote Mac, delete cropped image to reduce file size without losing image resolution quality

Tags: graphics, resolution, keynote, crop

I have lots of high-resolution images inserted into the Keynote which makes the file very large. Image masking in Keynote is very convenient for me. But I only want a small corner of the images shown in the slides, and I don't need the cropped part anymore. Reducing file size under the File menu loses image quality and the cropped images are still there. Is there any way to delete the cropped part to reduce file size without losing image resolution/quality?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest sequence of steps:

1. Copy masked image in Keynote
2. Cmd+N in Preview
3. Cmd+C
4. Paste in Keynote

You will have to process the images as crops before adding them to the slide deck since Keynote takes advantage of the entire image for moves, crops, masks and more.